# Change the password of “Sandbox Tester” user account on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

To test In-App Purchase features in an iOS app, we need fake user accounts on the fake App Store. Such accounts are defined on `iTunes Connect` > `Users And Roles` > `Sandbox Testers` web site. I see how to create such users on that web page, by clicking the `+` (Plus sign) inside a circle icon.

How do we reset the forgotten password on that account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You absolutely can change the password for sandbox users. Go to [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com)

Enter the sandbox email address. Either answer your security questions or have it send you an email.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect information.  You CAN NOT reset the password of a sandbox user this way.

Comment: Umm but I absolutely have. So there's that.

Answer (score -3):

You can't.  You just need to delete that user and add another on with a new email.

Comment: Incorrect. Deleting and attempting to re-create the Sandbox User in iTunes Connect generates the error message: That email address is already associated with an existing Apple ID.

Comment: You have to crate a new user with a different email.

Comment: Yeah, but that email also gets the same verification, which requires a password to login to verify.  Even a completely new user whose email address has not been used with an Apple ID previously gets the verification email with the username field prepopulated, but the password unknown.

Comment: Apple should just let us to see that stupid password. I'm the developer, I'm the only person who is using this account.